# Most suited technology for browser games?

Tags: mmo, browser

I was thinking about making a 2D MMO which I would in the long run support on various plattforms like desktop, mac, browser, android and ios.

The server will be c++/linux based and the first client would go in the browser.
So I have done some research and found that webgl and flash 11 support hardware accelerated rendering, I saw some other things like normal HTML5 painting.

So my question is, which technology should I use for such a project? My main goal would be that the users have a hassle free experience using what there hardware can give them with hardware acceleration. And the client should work on the most basic out-of-the-box pc's that any casual pc or mac user has. And another criteria would be that it should be developer friendly. I've messed with webgl abit for example and that would require writing a engine from scratch - which is acceptable but not preferred. Also, in case of non-actionscript, which kind language is most prefered in terms of speed and flexability. I'm not to fond of javascript due to the garbage collector but have learned to work around it.

Thank you for you time.

Comment: "Which tech should I use" questions are off topic for the site.  See the [faq].  And this question on our meta: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/695/are-what-should-i-use-to-do-x-questions-really-on-topic-and-good

Answer (score 3):

The best technology IMHO is HTML5. Because it has got some good support already and will be getting more very soon plus adobe is deprecating Flash.

http://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2011/11/flash-focus.html

For 2D development, you dont need WebGL or Hardware Acceleration (although it is a good thing) you can simply play around with the html5 canvas tag, i would recommend the following library: http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS it is javascript but similar to AS3 which might be what you want, i am learning it and have found it to be very useful, please note that it is being sponsored by Adobe and Microsoft so hopefully it is a good investment to make.

I Hope it helps :) best of luck for whatever you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: Adobe deprecating Flash for mobile apps. Also html5 sucks in terms of performance versus Flash 11. Html5 needs very long long path before it will same as today flash. I opened EasylJS Caching demo. OMG, it give me 15 fps on modern PC. Flash 9 can do much more then this "cached&fast" canvas. Html5 is good for banners. Use flash or Unity for MMO. Html5 just sucks.

Comment: @DenisErmolin I agree for most part, but this guy is asking for a technology to run games in Mobile/Desktop environment, i don't think it is going to take very long to mobile browsers to get better overtime, plus if you invest in flash now, you will have to redevelop the whole thing to convert it into HTML5 later which would double the cost in terms of time and money too (if you have a team for example).

Comment: There is no need to convert it into html5. What is the point doing it?

Comment: Because he wants to make browser games? I don't know if Unity apps can run on browsers.

Comment: http://unity3d.com/webplayer/. The only bad thing that it doesn't support Linux platform

Comment: you mean a plugin-dependent game player, now that will make it more slow (may be) than pure HTML5. But i may be wrong.... dont know much about Unity3D.

Comment: Approve your statement about higher perfomance of html5 then unity or/and flash. I already said about 15 fps on "fast" canvas.

Comment: Dont understand what you are trying to say or when did you say something about 15 FPS, can you be more specific?

Comment: http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS/demos/cache 11-15 FPS

Comment: You are trying to say that HTML5 doesn't perform good at 15 FPS?

Comment: I'm trying to say that 15 FPS actually sucks. It needs to be 60

Comment: Thats the point, they are running it at 15 FPS that is bad, HTML5 cant be blamed for that... try running that in 60 FPS and let me know how does it look like.

Comment: even with caching it cant grow more then 48. It still poor performance for such simple scene

Comment: the thing is that they are running it on that FPS just try running it on 60 FPS :)

Comment: I think you dont understand what is FPS

Comment: I do understand it my point is that "you can" set it to 60 FPS if it doesn't grow as much given the existing algorithm and friend truly our whole argument wont help anyone much other than ourselves :), Flash does perform better than HTML5 at the moment agreed. Is it a good investment? NO because its parent company is deprecating it, that was my point, performance issues can be worked around, and it will get better overtime, Flash will stay at its position in coming time, that is my point you can feel free to disagree, i wont be participating in the discussion anymore, bst of lck for evrythng:)

Comment: Also, that is not a "simple scene" it has many sprites which run fluently, see to do that with just GDI for example, no way that is going to happen, so it is okay i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Flash or Unity. Give up html5. Any Unity or Flash 11 app converts to native client on IOS / Android.